# Adding common controls to C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012, how do I add manifest entries to include things like Common Controls 6.0.0.0?  I've read on how to edit the manifest file directly here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx, however I don't have a manifest file in my solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the project properties to automatically embed manifest. You don't need to manually edit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229.aspx

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to change the way my list box displays. I've added comctl32.DLL in the method described there, used InitCommonControls, and then used CreateWindowEx to create a list box. However it still has the old design with a fixed width font. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Documentation says that you must be using InitCommonControlsEx instead for version 6.0 of ComCtl32.dll - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx